# Requesting access token for the same user from different places in linkedin

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm building an app using the REST api for linkedin. Everything works perfectly but I'm having a problem when requesting the access token for a user that has already requested the access token from an other device. For example a user opens his iPad and logs into linkedin from my own app, he gets the access token from linkedin and everything works fine. After that this same user wants to log in to my app from his android device, he logs into the app using his linkedIn credentials and everything works... but when the user goes back to his iPad and tries to make a request to linkedIn's API he gets back the following json:

{
errorCode = 0;
message = "Unable to verify access token";
requestId = 4GG948DQF; (I changed this number)
status = 401;
timestamp = 1371582181120;
}
Is there some limitation that when requesting a token the previous token is expired?

Is there any solution for it. to run with same user in different device.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello all, please help me i am awaiting for your response.Please help me.